# Syntax conventions for search terms: wildcard, literal, options, etc

Tags: search, filter

I have an application that presents a list of items and multiple filtering criteria.

Some of the filtering criteria take a string value for the filter, and the application currently supports basic wildcarding (* for anything, ? for any single character within a search term).

I've been asked to provide two changes to the syntax/capabilities for all fields that take a string:

- Allow searching for reserved characters (treat ? as a ? rather than as a wildcarded character, same for *: have some way to treat it as an asterisk instead of a wildcard.
- Support basic 'Or' functionality specified within the search term.  That is, match it if the value is 'String A' or 'String B'

I was considering wrapping the string in quotes for treating it as a literal.

e.g. "Question?" would only match 'Question?' but not 'Questions' as it currently does.

I have only come up with ideas for the 'Or' functionality like using a pipe | character between search terms.  I'd love something better.

Ultimately, I can do whatever, but I'm wondering if there's some sort of existing convention that would be simple, clear, obvious or ideally all of those.

So, my question is: **is there an existing syntax convention for search terms that allows wildcarding, literals, and alternatives that I could use rather than coming up with my own?**

The target user base would be something akin to a sysadmin.  I don't want something as complicated as regular expressions, but the application won't be used by someone's grandma... unless that grandma is a sysadmin, I guess.

Comment: This really depends on who your customers are. The * and ? placeholders originate from DOS; programmers tend to favor regular expressions syntax.

Comment: They're not developers.  It would be closer to sysadmin types, and regex would be too complicated.  I'm looking for something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to search - there can be only one reference (*sorry Bing and Yahoo*). [Google have a well documented guide](http://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en) what to use, and implicitly what not to use. Typically the asterix (*) means filling in the blank which is the same as wildcard, so that'll do. But using a question mark is not accounted for, so don't use that.

Quotations (" ") for an entire phrase, OR-statements, minus sign (-) for exclude, tilde sign (~) for similar, and two dots (..) for number range can also be used.

However, I'd be very careful to use a lot of characters for different "clever" meanings. I'd use quotations and wildcard only and skip the rest. But to be certain, and really know what is used, **consult your search query log** to know what your users use. That's the only way to be really sure.

Answer (score 0):

In programming (or doing anything with special characters), there is often a way in which you can **escape** the special character so that it reverts to just being text.  Often this is done by prepending the character with a special symbol (often \).  (Note: you have to be able to escape the escape - often this is just the special character repeated twice).

In your case, I could see this method working out - the question is whether or not your default interpretation of special characters should be as text or the commands they represent (i.e., should * mean wildcard by default, or should \* mean wildcard).  The answer is probably whichever usage is more common and convenient for your users.

Answer (score 0):

If the audience is System Admins and similar types - consider using a distilled form of SQL. That should be very familiar to admins and sysops

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Advanced Search of [CSA Illumina](http://www.csa.com/help/Search_Tools/boolean_operators.html). It uses boolean as well as positional operators and wildcards. To search for the wildcards themselves, the terms are simply put into quotes, as you did. That is quite intuitive.